# Select(and copy/edit) text from VS code Integrated terminal output(buffer scrollback) via keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code, integrated-terminal-window

Is there ability to select and copy(or edit) text from integrated terminal output(terminal scrollback) with keyboard.

For example Alacritty has [vi mode](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/docs/features.md#vi-mode): , Kitty has similar [feature](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/overview/#the-scrollback-buffer)

But how to achieve the same thing with vs code integrated terminal?
Is there some workarounds?

I know about zellij(CTRL+S+E), `screen` program but in that case I cannot use vscode (Ctrl+alt+R) shortcut to search across history. And some vs-code friendly solution will be the best, if one exist, using bash ideally(if possible) or another shell.

Comment: copying is supported: see whatever binds to `workbench.action.terminal.copySelection` by default in your keyboard shortcut UI. On Windows/Linux, it's `ctrl+shift+c`, which is pretty common in terminal emulators. You can change the keybinding too. See also other related commands: `workbench.action.terminal.copyLastCommandOutput`, `workbench.action.terminal.copySelectionAsHtml`.

Comment: why do you mean by "edit" in "_ability to copy(or edit) text_"? If you want to edit the screen see [ANSI escapes for moving the cursor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences).

Comment: @user I meant with keyboard. I know I can select with mouse, but I meant specifically use keyboard to select any text from previous terminal output.

Comment: @user by edit I mean for example open terminal output in Vs code. Similar to zellij edit terminal buffer scrollbar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182210

There are a few ways:

1. `Shift+tab` edit directly in integrated terminal, **if you have** `"editor.accessibilitySupport": "on"` in your `settings.json`.
   Vs code command for it is called: `workbench.action.terminal.focusAccessibleBuffer` and you can invoke it from command pallete.
2. Create your own shortcut to edit terminal output directly in vs code editor(instead of terminal itself).
   First add this shortcut to your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+a",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.terminal.selectAll",
        },
        {
          "command": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"
        },
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile"
        },
        {
          "command": "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

After that any time when in terminal press **ctrl+alt+a** to edit all terminal output in vs code newly created unsaved file.